# Sonarqube not applying rules

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins, sonarqube

I'll start of with some context:

1. I'm running a containerized instance of Sonarqube, Jenkins and a container with the .NET sdk for building/testing purposes.
2. All of these containers have Alpine Linux as base OS
3. Jenkins version: 2.121.2
4. Sonarqube version: 6.7.4 (build 38452)
5. .NET sdk version: 2.1.302
6. I'm testing on a sample directory that I cloned (some minor edits to confirm if SonarQube was functional) directory: https://github.com/Raisinpit/MSTest
7. My jenkins buildplan is as follows:

   - ssh to the container with the SDK and tell it to clone the repo
   - ssh to the container with the SDK and "dotnet publish" the directory
   - ssh to the container with the SDK and execute "dotnet test"
   - My sonarqube settings: [image: SonarQube settings]
8. Successful build proof: [image: Successful build proof]
9. SonarQube Result: [image: New image with rail and language tag removed]

I hope somebody knows why I am not getting any detections while sonarqube thinks it did it's job.

Comment: Only 1 file analyzed and calculate CPD for 0 files (step 8)?

Comment: I only have 1 file of C# code so that is correct however the CPD(copy/paste detector) doesn't even include that file. As far as I can see I have not altered the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your project homepage screenshot omits the top right rail, which holds line count per language that could have been very helpful.

But going by your Jenkins settings screenshot, you're using the very-long-deprecated `sonar.language` property to restrict analysis to C# files, and then not performing a "proper" C# analysis. This is likely the cause.

Take a look at the docs on how to analyze .NET via Jenkins: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild

Comment: I have updated the last image, it now includes the rail and the language tag is gone from my jenkins settings